# C# WPF Binding: Textbox and Listbox inside DockPanel, using ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding

This example is from a textbook, which I believe there are some mistakes in it.

In this example, a class **Nickname** with two properties, **Name** and **Nick**, is created, and a ObservableCollection **Nicknames** is created to collect Nickname. In the View, there are two textboxes for users to fill in name and nickname, and a button to add these two values to Nicknames and show item on Listbox; mutually the two textboxes should show the name and nickname if certain item is selected in Listbox.

However, the two values are always Jack and Joe in the listbox and I believe the problem is more than likely on:

```
public Nickname() : this("Jack", "Joe") { }
```

How do I fix this problem? Or, is there any suggestion other than dock panel to fulfill the requirement?

**Window1.xaml :**

```
<DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Name: </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="50"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Nick: </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Nick}" Width="50"/>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="addButton">Add</Button>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />:
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nick}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs :**

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.addButton.Click += addButton_Click;
        // create a nickname collection
        this.names = new Nicknames();
        // make data available for binding
        dockPanel.DataContext = this.names;
    }
    void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.names.Add(new Nickname());
    }
```

**Nickname.cs :**

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void Notify(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    string name;
    public string Name {...}
    string nick;
    public string Nick {...}

    public Nickname() : this("Jack", "Joe") { }

    public Nickname(string name, string nick)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Nick = nick;
    }
```

**Nicknames.cs :**

```
public class Nicknames : ObservableCollection<Nickname> { }
```

Comment: `public Nickname() : this("Jack", "Joe") { }` initialises each instance of the class with Jack, Joe. From the code given, this is the expected behaviour because there are no other names/nicknames in your code. Can you change these values (Jack/Joe) in the textboxes? Your problem might be that you need to click 'Add' before you change the name/nickname, rather than changing it and then adding.

Comment: Yes, as I said I found the problem but I have no idea how to fix it, and yes absolutely the user is allowed to change the values in the textboxes. I don't think it make sense to click 'Add' before changing the name/nickname, is there any other way to fulfill this lab's requirement?

Comment: What is the behaviour you're wanting? You keep mentioning the requirements, but you haven't stated what they are. Are you saying that you'd prefer the 'new' nickname to be added to the listbox AFTER the user has entered the names in the textboxes? The example you've provided is a working solution - there are no obvious mistakes, but it appears your requirements are different.

Comment: oitee, firstly the two textboxes are for users to fill in name &nickname. Once the user click Add button, the name & nickname should be added as one item and showed in the Listbox. Besides, after several pairs of name & nickname are added, the user can randomly select one item in Listbox and the corresponding name & nickname should be showed in the two textboxes. In this example, however, no matter what name & nickname you add, the item is always "Jack" & "Joe".